# Callback on function call in $.each

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback, each

I call a function in an $.each loop, but i want to make sure, that the next iteration is not called until the previous function is done.

```
$(".btn_loadfavorites").on("click",function(event){
 $.getJSON('utility/get_user_compare_pages.php', {uid: user}, function(rsp) {
  $.each(rsp, function(i, favorite_pageid) {
   loadNewFacebookPage(favorite_pageid);
  });
 });  
});
```

Here is the function (I stripped it of the unimportant stuff):

```
function loadNewFacebookPage(newfbpage){

  if (isUrl(newfbpage) || newfbpage.substr(0,3) == "www"){
    newfbpage = newfbpage.substr(newfbpage.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
  }

  $.getJSON( "https://graph.facebook.com/"+newfbpage+"?fields=picture,name,category,likes,talking_about_count,link,website" )
  .done(function( rsp ) {
      $('#loadmodal').modal('show');
      var newpageid = rsp.id;
      $("*[data-pcpageid]").each(function(i, elm) {
        if(newpageid == $(this).data("pcpageid")){
          pageexists = true;
          alert('Page has already been added');
          return;
        }
      });
      if(pageexists == false){
        pagename = rsp.name.split(" ");
        pagepicture = rsp.picture.data.url;
        $('.grid_fbpages').append("<li class='grid_li_fbpages' data-pcpageid='"+newpageid+"' style='max-width:20%;'><img src='"+pagepicture+"' class='img-circle' style='display:inline;margin-right:15px;'><h4 style='display:inline;'>"+pagename[0]+"</h4><a href='javascript:void(0)' class='btn_removefbpage' style='float:right' data-pcpageid='"+newpageid+"'>&#10005</a> <a href='javascript:void(0)' class='btn_addtofavorites' style='float:right' data-pcpageid='"+newpageid+"'>&#9733;</a><hr>Likes: "+rsp.likes+"<br>PTAT: "+rsp.talking_about_count+"<br><br></li>");
        //GET POSTS
        $.getJSON('utility/get_compare_posts.php', {access_token: access_token, pid: newpageid}, function(rsp) {
          $.each(rsp, function(postId, data) {

            //TOP POSTS
            if (data.hasOwnProperty('likes')){
              top_posts_likes.push(data.likes.like_count);
              if (data.hasOwnProperty('comments')){
                top_posts_comments.push(data.comments.comment_count);
              }else{
                top_posts_comments.push('0');
              }
              top_posts_message.push(data.message);
              top_posts_id.push(data.postId);
            }
          });

          //TOP POSTS
          $(".grid_topposts").append("<li data-pcpageid='"+newpageid+"' style='max-width:20%;text-align:left;'><img src='"+pagepicture+"' class='img-circle' style='display:inline;margin-right:15px;'><h4 style='display:inline;'>"+pagename[0]+"</h4></li>");
          most_popular_post_index = top_posts_likes.indexOf(Math.max.apply(Math, top_posts_likes));
          $.getJSON( "https://graph.facebook.com/"+top_posts_id[most_popular_post_index]+"?fields=picture&access_token="+access_token+"", function(rsp) {
            $(".grid_topposts").append("<li data-pcpageid='"+newpageid+"' style='max-width:20%;'><img src='"+rsp.picture+"'><br>"+top_posts_message[most_popular_post_index]+"<br>Likes: "+top_posts_likes[most_popular_post_index]+" Comments: "+top_posts_comments[most_popular_post_index]+"</li>");
              top_posts_likes.splice(most_popular_post_index,1);
              top_posts_message.splice(most_popular_post_index,1);
              top_posts_id.splice(most_popular_post_index,1);
              top_posts_comments.splice(most_popular_post_index,1);

              most_popular_post_index = top_posts_likes.indexOf(Math.max.apply(Math, top_posts_likes));
              $.getJSON( "https://graph.facebook.com/"+top_posts_id[most_popular_post_index]+"?fields=picture&access_token="+access_token+"", function(rsp) {
                $(".grid_topposts").append("<li data-pcpageid='"+newpageid+"' style='max-width:20%;'><img src='"+rsp.picture+"'><br>"+top_posts_message[most_popular_post_index]+"<br>Likes: "+top_posts_likes[most_popular_post_index]+" Comments: "+top_posts_comments[most_popular_post_index]+"</li>");
                  top_posts_likes.splice(most_popular_post_index,1);
                  top_posts_message.splice(most_popular_post_index,1);
                  top_posts_id.splice(most_popular_post_index,1);
                  top_posts_comments.splice(most_popular_post_index,1);

                  most_popular_post_index = top_posts_likes.indexOf(Math.max.apply(Math, top_posts_likes));
                  $.getJSON( "https://graph.facebook.com/"+top_posts_id[most_popular_post_index]+"?fields=picture&access_token="+access_token+"", function(rsp) {
                    $(".grid_topposts").append("<li data-pcpageid='"+newpageid+"' style='max-width:20%;'><img src='"+rsp.picture+"'><br>"+top_posts_message[most_popular_post_index]+"<br>Likes: "+top_posts_likes[most_popular_post_index]+" Comments: "+top_posts_comments[most_popular_post_index]+"</li>");
                      top_posts_likes.splice(most_popular_post_index,1);
                      top_posts_message.splice(most_popular_post_index,1);
                      top_posts_id.splice(most_popular_post_index,1);
                      top_posts_comments.splice(most_popular_post_index,1);
                  });
              });
          });
          //END TOP POSTS  

        });
      }
  })
  .fail(function( error ) {
    alert('Did not find any match - Please try again with another name, ID or URL');

  });
}
```

Thanks

Comment: is `loadNewFacebookPage` asynchronous

Comment: It is asynchronous, as it is placed inside the each loop

Comment: How can i make it synchronous?

Comment: `It is asynchronous, as it is placed inside the each loop` is simply not true. Does loadNewFacebookPage call with AJAX for example or does anything asynchronous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.each()` is synchronous. It's just a loop that calls a function directly, nothing fancy or mysterious about it. In your code, `$.each()` will call `loadNewFacebookPage()`, that function will run to completion, and then `$.each()` will move on to the next element.

But is that what you're really asking about? `loadNewFacebookPage()` sounds like it's probably an asynchronous function. If it is, are you saying that you want to wait until the asynchronous activity has completed before moving on to the next loop iteration? The `$.each()` loop won't do that. Nor would an ordinary `for` loop. Instead, `loadNewFacebookPage()` would need to provide a completion callback, and that callback would advance a "loop" variable.

If you can tell more about `loadNewFacebookPage()`—in particular whether it has a completion callback or one could be added—then it would be more clear what to do.

For example, suppose `loadNewFacebookPage()` takes a second argument which is a completion callback function. Then you could write code like this:

```
$.getJSON( url, { uid: user }, function( rsp ) {
    var i = 0;
    next();
    function next() {
        if( i < rsp.length ) {
            var favorite_pageid = rsp[i++];
            loadNewFacebookPage( favorite_pageid, next );
        }
    }
});
```

Suppose that `loadNewFacebookPage()` were using the `$.ajax()` function to load the data. (It probably isn't doing that, is it? But this will serve to illustrate.) Then you might do something like:

```
function loadNewFacebookPage( id, done ) {
    $.ajax({
        url: makeUrlFromId( id ),
        success: function( data ) {
            doStuffWithData( data );
            done();
        }
    });
}
```

I'm omitting a bunch of stuff here like error handling just to illustrate an example.

Comment: Thanks. Not really familiar with the synchronous vs. asynchronous. loadNewFacebookPage takes a pageid and gets data from the respective facebook page. It then appends the data. The error happens when I make a $.getJSON for post pictures (For the 3 top posts of the fb page). This takes a short time, meaning that meanwhile, the each loop has called the next loadNewFacebookPage() before the post pictures are ready. How do I make the callback?

Comment: And yes, I want to wait until the asynchronous activity has been completed before moving on to next loop iteration :)

Comment: And then at the end of my loadNewFacebookPage i call the next() function?

Comment: Right, `loadNewFacebookPage()` is performing an asynchronous operation: the function starts the page loading and then returns immediately. How you'd add a callback to that function would depend on the code in the function. But there should be someplace in that code where it has a callback that is run after the page data is loaded. That's where you would call the `next` callback. If you can post the code for that function it should be easy to advise.

Comment: *And then at the end of my loadNewFacebookPage i call the next() function?* Not exactly. There must be some kind of callback already being used inside that function. That's where you'd call `next()` - and not by calling it directly but by calling the (new) second parameter to `loadNewFacebookPage()`.

Comment: Just posted the function

Comment: Whoa - you have a lot of nested `$.getJSON()` calls there. I posted a simplified general example, but your situation is much more complicated than that. Am I right in assuming that you want *all* of those `$.getJSON()` calls to complete before moving to the next step in the top level loop in the click handler?

Comment: I know. But its because I need the data from the first json call to execute the other, and so on. FB API..... But yeah, you are right about that

Comment: It is the three JSON calls at the bottom (//TOP POSTS), that does not finish until the next iteration is called. So should I make the next() callback in the callback of the last getJSON?

Comment: You are my savior! ;) It works. Although it is a bit slow when I have a lot of pages, I guess it is the only way to do it.

Comment: It seems to me that it should be possible to do all this without having to delay the loop at all. Perhaps when you call `loadNewFacebookPage()` several times in a row, the eventual async callbacks in that function step on each other. It looks like they are using some shared `top_posts_xxxx` variables. That could be where the problem is.

Comment: That is exactly where the problem is. What would you suggest I do then?